# cmake: how to check if preprocessor is defined

Tags: cmake, preprocessor

I can't get `cmake` to test if a preprocessor has been defined or not. Eg:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project (cmake-test)
add_definitions(-DOS=LINUX)

if(NOT <what condition goes here?>)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "OS is not defined")
endif()
```

The following tests don't work:

```
if (NOT COMMAND OS)
if (NOT DEFINED OS)
if (NOT OS)
```

I can get it to work by using `set()` and just testing for a regular `cmake` variable and then defining the preprocessor macro. Eg:

```
set(OS LINUX)
if (OS)
    add_definitions(-DOS=${OS})
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "OS is not defined")
endif()
```

In case, you're wondering why I need to test it if the variable/preprocessor is in the *same* file, it's because in the final implementation these will come from an external file which is `include`ed in the main CMakeFile.txt Eg:

```
include(project_defs.txt)
if (OS)
    ....
```

Comment: What do you mean by pre-processor? CMake does not have one...

Comment: CMake automatically defines several variables, which describes the system. So you may check (in `if` command) these variables for include OS-dependent code. See [Variables That Provide Information](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-variables.7.html#variables-that-provide-information).

Comment: @usr1234567 by pre-processor I meant a variable defined by the `-D` option to `gcc` (same as `#define`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev `OS` was just an example. What I'm trying to define are custom properties for my project, so `cmake` won't know about them.

Comment: So, what is a problem with your approach (setting CMake variable, and checking it then)? If cmake script is *included* (via `include()` command), then all its definitions are seen by the caller. (They say, `that include()` doesn't introduce *scope of variables definition*).

Comment: @Tsyvarev there's no 'problem' per-se. It's just a little more verbose, because I first have do a `set()`, then check for it's existence and then do `add_definitions()`. It would be nice to make just one `add_definitions()` call. I'm still exploring @arrowd 's answer of using `get_target_property()` and inspect the `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` property.

Answer (score 4):

This is to complete the answer by arrowd.

I also tried the COMPILE_DEFINITIONS option as mentioned above by arrowd unsuccessfully.

Following the documentation of CMake, at least for version 3.x, it turns out that when you call `add_definitions()` in CMake, it adds the definitions to the COMPILE_DEFINITIONS ***directory*** property.

Therefore, lets say you are defining the following as per your code:

```
add_definitions(-DOS=LINUX)
```

To retrieve the string with the definitions added into the variable "MYDEFS" you can use the following lines in CMake:

```
get_directory_property(MYDEFS COMPILE_DEFINITIONS)
MESSAGE( STATUS "Compile defs contain: " ${MYDEFS} )
```

Then you can check if in `${MYDEFS}` the define you are looking for exists or not. For instance

```
if(MYDEFS MATCHES "^OS=" OR MYDEFS MATCHES ";OS=")
    MESSAGE( STATUS "OS defined" )
else()
    # You can define your OS here if desired
endif()
```

Comment: Since there may be multiple definitions added, the `${MYDEFS}` contain multiple variables, and the not quoted `${MYDEFS}` will mess up. I suggest use `"${MYDEFS}"`.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, all definitions that are passed to the compiler are controlled by CMake. That is, you create a CMake variable with

```
option(SOMEFEATURE "Feature description" ON)
```

or

```
set(OS "" CACHE STRING "Select your OS")
```

User sets them via `cmake -D OS=DOS` or in the CMake GUI. Then you can use `if()` operator to conditionally `add_definitions()` to the compiler command line.

**UPDATE:**

If you really want to access preprocessor flags, there is a [COMPILE_DEFINITIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/prop_tgt/COMPILE_DEFINITIONS.html) target property. You can access it this way:

```
get_target_property(OUTVAR target COMPILE_DEFINITIONS)
```

Comment: So then the second approach I mentioned is probably the only way to do this I guess.It would've been nice if `cmake` would allow testing stuff set via `add_definitions`.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I did look in the `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` as the docs for `add_definitions()` mention it. However I was unable to fetch the defines specified (I tried your suggestion of using `get_target_property` but got `NOTFOUND` instead). I'm using `cmake 2.8.12.2`

Comment: This is strange, because even for 2.8 such property exists: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#prop_tgt:COMPILE_DEFINITIONS Try using more recent CMake.