# if condition in .CMake files

Tags: cmake

I have the following variable in a .cmake file:

```
add_definitions(-DENABLE_TEST)

if(DEFINED ENABLE_TEST)
    message("ENABLE_TEST    defined")
else()
    message("ENABLE_TEST    NOT defined")
endif()
```

I have to use the variable in other CMakelists.txt too.

Why does the above "if" always coming out as not defined?
How do I check if the variable is defined or not?

Answer (score 4):

The [`add_definitions()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_definitions.html) command adds compile definitions to the compilation of your source files. It does **not** define CMake variables. The `if(DEFINED ...` syntax checks for the existence of CMake or environment variables, not the existence of compile definitions.

You can use the [`set()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html) CMake command to define CMake variables, then subsequently, check for their existence in this manner:

```
set(ENABLE_TEST 1)

if(DEFINED ENABLE_TEST)
    message("ENABLE_TEST    defined")
else()
    message("ENABLE_TEST    NOT defined")
endif()
```

Comment: If I use set() then can I use the ENABLE_TEST flag in .c files?

Comment: @RKum No, `set()` is used to define **CMake** variables, not preprocessor compile definitions. The `add_definitions()` and `target_compile_definitions()` commands are used to define preprocessor flags that can be used in `.c` files.

Comment: @RKum For checking if a preprocessor compile definition has already been specified earlier in your CMake, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34937671/cmake-how-to-check-if-preprocessor-is-defined) response.